# Flip! plugin content as a hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make the content of the [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) box a click-able hyperlink.

I'm new to jquery, this is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("#flipPad a:not(.revert)").bind("mouseover", function () {
                var $this = $(this);


                $("#flipbox").flip({
                    direction: $this.attr("rel"),
                    color: $this.attr("rev"),
                    content: $this.attr('title'),

                })
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>


 <div id="flipbox" >Select a contact option below</div>
 <div id="flipPad">
       <a href="#" class="left" rel="rl" rev="#39AB3E" title="johntk86@gmail.com">Email</a>
        <a href="#" class="top" rel="bt" rev="#66b7d2" title="0857100495">Mobile</a>
        <a href="#" class="bottom" rel="tb" rev="#dd4b39" title="Click to visit my G+ profile">Google+</a>
        <a href="#" class="right" rel="lr" rev="#007baf" title="Click to visit my in profile">LinkedIn</a>

  </div>
```

At the moment the title element of the herf in the flip pad is my content,

is it possible to make the content a hyperlink?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the specific programming problem you are encountering?

Comment: When I hover over each flipPad, it changes the content of the flipbox.
I want to be able to make the content displayed in the flipbox a hyperlink.

I've tried in vain, but cannot get the results I want.